# Volley no conecta con API

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley, volley

Estoy haciendo una pantalla para un inicio de sesión sencillo con el fin de probar la funcionalidad de un API en desarrollo pero al momento de enviar la peticion con Volley no me regresa nada. Estuve intentando tambien esperar por la respuesta y no recibe nada. El modo debug no muestra ningun error de conexion. Este es el codigo de del layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextUsername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Usuario"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editTextUsername"
        android:hint="Contraseña"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editTextPassword"
        android:text="Iniciar Sesión"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Y este es el codigo para la funcion del login:

```
package com.protocoderspoint.registration_login;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editTextUsername;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private Button buttonLogin;
    public static int TIMEOUT_MS = 5000;        //5 seconds

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        editTextUsername = findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        buttonLogin = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Obtener el nombre de usuario y la contraseña ingresados
                String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString();
                String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                // Realizar una solicitud HTTP para iniciar sesión en el servidor
                login(username, password);
            }
        });
    }

    private void login(String username, String password) {
        // URL del servidor de autenticación (reemplaza con tu propia URL)
        String loginUrl = "https://convivetufinanciera.com.mx:9418/eme/v1.0/auth";

        // Crear un objeto JSON para enviar los datos de inicio de sesión
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString();
                String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                // Crear un objeto JSON para los datos de inicio de sesión
                JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonRequest.put("username", username);
                    jsonRequest.put("password", password);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Configurar la cola de solicitudes Volley con el HurlStack personalizado
                RequestQueue requestQueue = createRequestQueueWithCustomHurlStack();

                // Realizar la solicitud de inicio de sesión
                login(requestQueue, jsonRequest);
            }
        });
    }

    private RequestQueue createRequestQueueWithCustomHurlStack() {
        try {
            // Crear un TrustManager que confíe en todos los certificados
            TrustManager[] trustAllCertificates = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return null;
                        }
                        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        }
                        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        }
                    }
            };

            // Crear un contexto SSL personalizado
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCertificates, new SecureRandom());

            // Obtener el socket factory confiable
            javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            // Crear un HurlStack personalizado que use el socket factory y no verifique el nombre de host
            HurlStack hurlStack = new HurlStack(null, sslSocketFactory) {
                @Override
                protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
                    HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) super.createConnection(url);
                    httpsURLConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                            return true; // No verificamos el nombre de host
                        }
                    });
                    return httpsURLConnection;
                }
            };

            // Inicializar la cola de solicitudes Volley con el HurlStack personalizado
            return Volley.newRequestQueue(this, hurlStack);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        }
    }

    private void login(RequestQueue requestQueue, JSONObject jsonRequest) {
        // URL del servidor de inicio de sesión (reemplaza con tu propia URL)
        String loginUrl = "https://convivetufinanciera.com.mx:9418/eme/v1.0/auth/";

        // Realizar una solicitud POST con Volley
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, loginUrl, jsonRequest,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            // Manejar la respuesta del servidor
                            boolean success = response.getBoolean("success");
                            String message = response.getString("message");

                            if (success) {
                                // Inicio de sesión exitoso, realizar acciones adicionales
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Sesion iniciada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                // Inicio de sesión fallido
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Sesion no iniciada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Manejar errores de la solicitud, incluido TimeoutError
                        if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                            // TimeoutError: La solicitud superó el tiempo de espera
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error de tiempo de espera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            // Otros errores
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error de red", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

        /*request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                TIMEOUT_MS,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
        ));*/

        // Agregar la solicitud a la cola de Volley
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

De momento estoy ignorando los certificados por un problema, pero en si la aplicacion no me responde con nada. De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Hola. ¿No ves nada tampoco en la tostadora? Pon puntos de interrupción en la primera línea del `try` que tienes en el `onResponse`, así como en el `catch` y en el `onErrorResponse` así sabrás por dónde está pasando tu código  y podrás examinar el estado de los objetos en ese punto. Puede que el XML del layout sea irrelevante para este caso, supongo que ves tu botón y que puedes hacer click en él. Por si acaso, puedes poner también un punto de interrupción en el onClick del botón. Otra cosa, ¿por qué comentaste la política de reintentos? Conviene mantenerla cuando usas Volley.

Comment: Que se obtiene en "response" ?, Que mensajes se muestra en el Toast?